# What is this very isolated, modern aviation/heliport in Northwest Antelope Valley, California?

Tags: airport-identification

There's a modern facility at 118 53' 16" 34 9' 28" or [about 9 miles north of Neenach, California](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Neenach,+CA+93536/@34.9256706,-118.5313406,870m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c20b6431b2dba7:0x9be7eea85a709d1d!8m2!3d34.780571!4d-118.5809521). It has 5 hangars - 1 very large, 1 medium, 3 small - with other large buildings and a large water tank (a million gallons?). It sits in the foothills of the south side of the Tehachapi Mountains. The only land access is a meager dirt road, almost a 2 track.

Any suggestions as to what it is?

Comment: Any suggestions about what?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Those don't really look like they are, or ever have been runways. You can see a large X painted on both of them, which indicates they aren't runways now.

Comment: This isn't and never was an airport. Its the Tejon Ranch facility that Northrup built in the mid 1980's for research on radar cross sections. It closed in 2010 due to interference from nearby solar and wind installations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be the Northrop Tejon Ranch RCS facility. It is used for testing of radar cross sections. There’s a page [here](http://clui.org/ludb/site/northrop-tejon-ranch-radar-cross-section-facility) with a little more info on it.